# Jquery upload file plugin with java servlet

Tags: java, jquery, servlets, jquery-file-upload

I am using jquery upload file plugin [Jquery file upload plugin](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#single).

I want to use it with Java not PHP.

Following is my code:

```
      <af:resource type="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url:'GetFileSevlet',
    fileName:"myfile",
        dataType:document,
        showDelete: true,
        showDownload:true,
         statusBarWidth:600,
        dragdropWidth:600,
      maxFileSize:200*1024
    });
});
    </af:resource>
      <af:form id="f1" usesUpload="true" >
     <div id="fileuploader">Upload</div>
```

I make a servlet, but I am not sure how can I get these files in servlet.

How to get these files in servlet? With this I am able to see upload screen and able to upload file but not able to get these files in servlet from request.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Fixed sentences, grammar, ect.

Comment: It's not different from when using plain HTML. The duplicate answers how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should map `GetFileSevlet` url to your servlet in `web.xml` configuration file. Then you should receive data from `request` object in servlet implementation.

Comment: I already mapped my servlet in web.xml . I am able to get hit in my servlet. But how do I get object of files in servlet. I need help in that

Comment: `(request.getParameter("attachment")).getBytes();`